# Linux: How would I pipe text into a program properly?

Tags: linux, file, terminal, command, pipe

I've looked but can't find anything. A program for example, a TTS I use lets you do the following:

```
~#festival -tts | echo "I am to be spoken"
```

Which is really nice, but for programs I use such as hexdump, I don't know how to pipe text into it. I can REALLY use some of these things, some examples I tried (but failed) are like so:

```
~#gtextpad < dmesg
      //(how do I put the contents into the text pad for display? not just into a file)
~#hexdump | echo "I am to be put into hexdump"
      //(How do I get hexdump to read the echo? It normally reads a file such as foo.txt..)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here are some ways to pass text to hexdump

Stdin:

`echo "text" | hexdump`

Here document

```
hexdump <<EOF
text
EOF
```

to process entire file

```
hexdump file
```

Comment: Ah. The other way around, Now I can do some useful automated things I've wanted.

Answer (score 5):

On bash, you can also do

```
hexdump <<< "Pipe this text into hexdump"
```

Comment: See this question for an explanation of `<<<`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean

Answer (score 3):

The data flow in a pipeline (series of commands separated by pipe symbols) flows from left to right.  Thus, the output from command1 below goes to the input of command2, and so on.

```
command1 |
command2 |
command3 arg1 arg2 arg3 |
sort |
more
```

So, to get the output of 'echo' into 'hexdump', use:

```
echo "I am to be dumped" | hexdump
```

I don't see how the 'festival' command you show can work.  The shell does enough plumbing that without making unwarranted assumptions and doing a lot of skulduggery and then still relying on scheduling decisions in the kernel to get things 'right', I don't see how it can be made to work.

Answer (score 2):

From the `hexdump(1)` man page:

> The hexdump utility is a filter which displays the specified files, or the standard input, if no files are specified, in a user specified format.

So:

```
echo "I am to be put into hexdump" | hexdump
```